Position where last x halfmoves are determined
What is the largest integer x such that there exists a position such that:

That position can occur in a legal chess game
It is possible to prove at least x halfmoves have been played
It is possible to determine what the board position was x moves ago.
It is possible to determine the last x halfmoves played

Position includes information about side to move, castling rights and en passant rights. By legal, I mean legal under FIDE laws.
I know x=20 is possible.

The question is interesting. But even the question is "The maximum number of accurate last single moves?" It can be divided into 4 parts:
a) without the 50-move rule (standard set of pieces);
b) without the 50-move rule (overset);
c) with the 50-move rule (standard);
d) with the rule of 50 moves (overset).

As of July 2024, I believe 109 single moves is the record.
[Note that the terminology used in the retro community is "single moves" rather than "halfmoves", so I've stuck with that. But it's the same thing: "ply".]
This document at Thomas Brand's site gives general length records for retractions up to Aug-2022, and I doubt there are significant improvements since then. Authored by Dmitrij Baibikov, Alain Brobecker & Thierry Le Gleuher, it has evolved over 15 years of work.
According to them, the current records for last moves are:



Type
What is this?
Record Single Moves
Author




Type A
not told whose move; no check
107
Le Gleuher


Type B
told whose move
108
Le Gleuher


Type C
check
109
Le Gleuher


Type D
duplex
102/103 = 102
Le Gleuher


Type E
colour the pieces; no obvious check
22
Baibikov


Type F
colour the pieces; obvious check
27
Baibikov



You can check out the paper for yourself and see the current length records for each feasible number of pieces, together with detailed solutions. In this post, I just show:
(1) the overall record - not surprisingly it’s Type C.
(2) a detailed solution by Henrik Juel for the Type D record.
[Title "Type C: Last 109 single moves? - Thierry Le Gleuher C p.481 Die Schwalbe 291, 06/2018"]
[FEN "8/8/6P1/2p5/1P1PPk2/1pPPprp1/BPrqbRPB/NbbR1rKN w - - 0 1"]


[Title "Type D: Last 102 single moves? Duplex - Thierry Le Gleuher R546 The Problemist 27-6, p. 229, 11/2019"]
[FEN "8/6p1/8/5PP1/1P3pRP/1p1PPrrr/n2pRrPR/1BNKbk1r w - - 0 1"]

Comment adapted from Henrik Juel who wrote:

Here is the solution from the May 2020 issue of The Problemist from www.theproblemist.org, a treasure-trove of info.


Retroanalysis: The wPs captured
the 4 missing black units. Thus, wPb4 comes from b2, and (Pa2)
promoted to the extra wR on a8 with (Pa7) letting it pass by switching
to the b file (first capture of the 3 missing white units). (Pb7) must
have promoted to a rook on a1 or c1 (second capture). (Ph7) must have
moved onto the g file (third and final capture) in order to be
captured. Thus (Pc7) and (Pe7) promoted to rooks on the c and e files,
respectively. It is not possible to immediately take back a4xb3 or
c2xd3. The retro-move e4xf5 is forbidden since then the bP which
promoted on e1 cannot retract to e5. Black can only move in the
southeast cage, while White’s bishop is free to oscillate between c2
and b1.
Black to move: retro 1.Bc2-b1 Kg1-f1 2.Bb1-c2 Rf1-f2 3.Bc2-b1 Rf2-f3
4.Bb1-c2 Rf3-g3 5.Bc2-b1 Rg3-h3 6.Rh3-h2 Rh2-h1 7.Bb1-c2 Kh1-g1 8.Bc2-b1 Rg1-f1 9.Bb1-c2 Rf1-f2 10.Bc2-b1 Rf2-f3 11.Bb1-c2 Rf3-g3 12.Rg3-h3 Rh3-h2
13.Bc2-b1 Kh2-h1 14.Bb1-c2 Rh1-g1 15.Bc2-b1 Kg1-h2 16.Bb1-c2 Rh2-h1
17.Bc2-b1 Kh1-g1 18.Bb1-c2 Rg1-f1 19.Bc2-b1 Rf1-f2 20.Bb1-c2 Rf2-f3
21.Rf3-g3 Rg3-h3 22.Bc2-b1 Rh3-h2 23.Bb1-c2 Kh2-h1 24.Bc2-b1 Rh1-g1
25.Bb1-c2 Kg1-h2 26.Bc2-b1 Rh2-h1 27.Bb1-c2 Kh1-g1 28.Bc2-b1 Rg1-f1
29.Bb1-c2 Rf1-f2 30.Rf2-f3 Rf3-g3 31.Bc2-b1 Rg3-h3 32.Bb1-c2 Rh3-h2
33.Bc2-b1 Kh2-h1 34.Bb1-c2 Rh1-g1 35.Bc2-b1 Rg1-f1 36.Rf1-f2 Bf2-e1
37.Re1-f1 Rf1-g1 38.Bb1-c2 Rg1-h1 39.Bc2-b1 Kh1-h2 40.Bb1-c2 Rh2-h3
41.Bc2-b1 Rh3-g3 42.Bb1-c2 Bg3-f2 43.Bc2-b1 Rf2-f1 44.Bb1-c2 Rf1-g1
45.Bc2-b1 Kg1-h1 46.Bb1-c2 Rh1-h2 47.Bc2-b1 Kh2-g1 48.Bb1-c2 Rg1-h1
49.Bc2-b1 Kh1-h2 50.Bb1-c2 Rh2-h3 51.h3-h4 Bh4-g3 52.Bc2-b1 then 52…Rg3-f3 (or 52...Bg3-h4 53.Bb1-c2 Bh4-g3…) 53.Bb1-c2 Rf3-f2
54.Bc2-b1 Rf2-f1 55.Bb1-c2 Rf1-g1 56.Bc2-b1 Kg1-h1 57.Bb1-c2 Rh1-h2 58.h2-h3 Rh3-g3 59.Bc2-b1 Bg3-h4 60.Bb1-c2 Rh8-h3 etc…
The diagram position is a draw and the last 103 single moves are
determined.
White to move: retro 1... Kg1-f1 ... 51.h3-h4 Bh4-g3 52.Bc2-b1 then the same... Here, there are 99 single moves between the diagram position and the retro-move h3-h4. Of course, trying to insert another manoeuvre in the solution would lead
to an overshoot of the 101 single moves, which would be incompatible
with the 50 moves rule. Here only 102 last single moves are
determined. So, we have a new record for last single moves
for ‘D’ type (Duplex) with 25 pieces. (It is also the overall record
for Duplex.) With black to move, the same diagram is also a record
with 25 pieces.


This task is definitely not a record. I know longer. We just need to find her.

I do not know the author. I only have FEN KB6/QpN1p2p/r1pkP3/Rqp1p3/bRP5/brP5/pPP5/NB6

@ЭлсиРинген That is pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P0000228

Perhaps I will single out this task as a separate question. Because I still haven't figured out how many exact last moves there really are.

Good idea. I can search PDB for the applicable answers.

100: https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1339006 101: https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1011800

Oh, thank you very much. Otherwise, the task is very well-known. And no one indicates the author.

All these around 100 moves are tethered by 50M rule which I think helps on uniqueness. Means the path mast be tight with no little eddies. However there might be something way longer if we drop 50M rule

Without the 50 moves rule, the record is 55 single moves in total. In a superset. https://www.janko.at/Retros/Glossary/LastMove.htm#prec

But I do not know how many records are in the standard set.

The answer is perfect. But most of the records for the 50-move rule. This is one story. Without the 50-move rule, it's a different story. Plus another kit/over-kit again.

"However there might be something way longer if we drop 50M rule"
Exactly the opposite.
For example, in a problem of type D without the rule of 50M unique moves, instead of 102 there will be exactly 0.

Bc2-b1 Kg1-f1 2. Bb1-c2 Kf1-g1
And we came back to the starting position.


A good reference for this task is Dmitri Baibikov's Length records in 'Last single moves?' problems. Baibikov classifies such problems into types, of which the ones pertinent here are:

Type A: neither king is in check; the problem does not stipulate the turn player
Type B: neither king is in check; the problem stipulates the turn player
Type C: the turn player is in check

His records for the respective types are:
Type A: Gyula Breyer, Chess Amateur, 1922; FIDE Album, 1914-1944; correction: Gerd Wilts, Die Schwalbe, No. 7373, June 1991. PDB P0000228.
What were the last 96 single-moves?
[Title "Gyula Breyer, Chess Amateur, 1922; FIDE Album, 1914-1944; correction: Gerd Wilts, Die Schwalbe, No. 7373, June 1991. PDB P0000228."]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "KB6/QpN1p2p/r1pkP3/Rqp1p3/bRP5/brP5/pPP5/NB6 w - - 0 1"]

Type B: Andrei Kornilov, Shakhmatnaya Kompozitsia No. 38, 2000, 171 (v). Prize; Length records in 'Last single moves?' problems, Sep 2008, B25. PDB P1300399.
[Title "Andrei Kornilov, Shakhmatnaya Kompozitsia No. 38, 2000, 171 (v). Prize; *Length records in 'Last single moves?' problems*, Sep 2008, B25. PDB P1300399."]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "2kq1BNr/ppP1PQrB/2ppKPPn/4ppRP/6pp/1P6/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

Type C: Gyula Breyer, Chess Amateur, 1922; FIDE Album, 1914-1944; correction: Gerd Wilts, Die Schwalbe, No. 7373, June 1991 (v). PDB P1300402.
[Title "Gyula Breyer, Chess Amateur, 1922; FIDE Album, 1914-1944; correction: Gerd Wilts, Die Schwalbe, No. 7373, June 1991 (v). PDB P1300402."]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "KB6/qpN1p2p/r1pkP3/R1p1p3/bRP5/brP5/pPP5/NB6 w - - 0 1"]

